# xslt - grouping element and following element

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following structure. That is to say - I may have the following structure.

The output comes from a CMS and very often there is text in front of a table and after a table. In order to make the second stage in the transformation work, wrapping the the paragraph before the table and after the table inside an element is essential.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>and maybe some text here. it may or may not be here</p>
    <figure>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </figure>
    <p>Likely to be a paragraph here</p>
    <p>And here - often like: table 2, but nothing I can use</p>
    <figure>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </figure>
    <p>and another paragraph at the end of the table</p>
</div>
```

My goal is to get an output like below where the first paragraph in the beginning has it's own wrapper. then the combination of paragraph + table + paragraph is put inside a wrapper.

There might be some paragraphs at the end of the file and those should be wrapped as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>some text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <p>and maybe some text here. it may or may not be here</p>
        <figure>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>test</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </figure>
        <p>Likely to be a paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <p>And here - often like: table 2, but nothing I can use</p>
        <figure>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>test</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </figure>
        <p>another text at the end of the table</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am playing around with preceding and following + parent. Any pointers in the right direction would be of great help

I am restricted to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: An example is no substitute for rules.

Comment: True, I wrote the example inside the text-form-field and thus forgot to not follow XML-standards. I have corrected the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is well-defined. Given certain assumptions (which should be self-evident), and given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<body>
  <p>some text here</p>
  <p>and maybe some text here. it may or may not be here</p>
  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>
  <p>Likely to be a paragraph here</p>
  <p>And here - often like: table 2, but nothing I can use</p>
  <figure>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figure>
  <p>and another paragraph at the end of the table</p>
</body>
```

you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::figure] or following-sibling::*[1][self::figure])]" mode="stand-alone"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="figure">
            <div class="table">
                <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1][self::p]"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="stand-alone">
    <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<body>
   <div>
      <p>some text here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="table">
      <p>and maybe some text here. it may or may not be here</p>
      <figure>
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>test</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </figure>
      <p>Likely to be a paragraph here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="table">
      <p>And here - often like: table 2, but nothing I can use</p>
      <figure>
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>test</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </figure>
      <p>and another paragraph at the end of the table</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was just what I needed. Some tweaking on my end to get it exactly how I needed it to be, but this was definitely pointers in the right direction. Very much appreciated.